# TypeError at /cart/add_cart/7/ _cart_id() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

from urllib import request
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Cart, CartItem
from store.models import Product

## Create your views here.

def _cart_id():
cart = request.session.session_key
if not cart:
cart = request.session.create()
return cart

def add_cart(request, product_id):
product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
try:
cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request)) #get the cart using the cart_id present in the session
except Cart.DoesNotExist:
cart = Cart.objects.create(
cart_id = _cart_id(request)
)

```
cart.save()
 
try:
     cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
     cart_item.quantity += 1 #cart_item.quantity = cart_item.quantity + 1
     cart_item.save()
except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
        product = product,
        quantity = 1,
        cart = cart,
        
    )
    cart_item.save()
return HttpResponse(cart_item.product)
exit()
return redirect('cart')
```

def cart(request,):
return render(request, 'store/cart.html')

Hey, so basically when I'm running the server to test the "Add to cart" button I get this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SwT7.png)